# Mysql aggregating data with if statement

Tags: mysql, database

Simplified example of a problem I am trying to solve:

**EDIT - With PK**

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7be5d/1

**---**

I have two tables:

```
People
--------
| Name |
--------
| Mike |
| Jim  |
| Fred |
--------


HasBanana
------------------------
| Name  | Has_a_banana |
------------------------
| Mike  | N            |
| Mike  | N            |
| Mike  | N            |
| Mike  | N            |
| Mike  | Y            |
| Mike  | N            |
| Jim   | N            |
| Jim   | N            |
| Jim   | Y            |
| Jim   | N            |
| Jim   | N            |
| Fred  | N            |
| Fred  | N            |
| Fred  | N            |
| Fred  | N            |
| Fred  | N            |
| Fred  | N            |
------------------------
```

And a query:

```
select * from People
left join HasBanana on HasBanana.name = People.name;
```

This produces a table exactly the same as the HasBanana table above. What I would like to produce is a table grouped by People.name and showing Y if the person has ever been marked as having a banana.

So something like this:

```
HadBanana
------------------------
| Name  | Had_a_banana |
------------------------
| Mike  | Y            |
| Jim   | Y            |
| Fred  | N            |
------------------------
```

I know I can use the following to group by name

```
group by people.name;
```

but having issues doing the logic to say for each name if has_a_banana has ever been Y then set had_a_banana to Y.

Comment: You have no pk. this is problematic

Comment: @Strawberry I've not posted a real table I am actually working with. Only a simplified table to illustrate my point. Will add one though if it is really needed for the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
   p.name
   , case when x.name is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as had_a_banana
from people p
left outer join
(
  select 
     name 
  from bananas
  where has_a_banana = 'Y'
  group by name
) x
on x.name = p.name
group by p.name, x.name
```

I've checked this using your SQLFiddle link, although your Fiddle data does not match your question, so I get:

```
Fred  N
Jim   Y
Mike  N
```

(which seems to match your Fiddle data).

Comment: Thats perfect, they were both just randomly stuck in data. Now to try an integrate this into the query I am working with... wish me luck!

Comment: GROUP BY with no aggregating clauses? Performance benefits aside, I don't think we should encourage that!

Comment: @Strawberry what are aggregating clauses for a group by? Links to any reading material would be great :-)

Comment: The manual has a handful of pages on GROUP BY. Here's one: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: An aggregate clause, or aggregate function, is a function that does something on a group of values rather than one value. Think of `max(..)`, `group_concat(..)`. If you use `group by ...` without any of those you can probably move it to a sub-query, omit it entirely, or construct your query in a different way such that it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (bit of an ugly solution):

```
select people.name, max(has_a_banana) from people
left join bananas on bananas.name = people.name
group by people.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select people.id, people.name, case a.has_a_banana when 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end as has_a_banana from people
left join 
(select people.id, people.name, bananas.has_a_banana from people
left join bananas on bananas.name = people.name
where has_a_banana = 'Y'
group by people.name) as a 
on a.name = people.name
```

Should allow you to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.name
              , COALESCE(y.has_a_banana,x.has_a_banana) has_a_banana
           FROM bananas x
           LEFT 
           JOIN bananas y
             ON y.name = x.name
            AND y.has_a_banana = 'y'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7be5d/25